# SharePoint 2010 - The trial period for this product has expired

Tags: installation, sharepoint-2010

After installing SharePoint 2010 successfully on Windows Server 2008 SP2, 
I tried to create a Team Site, but it gives me the following error: 
**"The trial period for this product has expired"**

i tried to google it, but with no luck!
can anyone help please ?
note that i have installed SharePoint as a **Single Server with built-in database** on a Windows Server 2008 SP2 (not activated yet but it's trail period still valid for 59 days)

Comment: I removed the "solved" bit from the title, as we don't use that here. It's enough to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved when i ran **SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard**

Comment: You should mark your question as solved with the checkmark under your answer.

Comment: thanks alot for your note, but regarding the checkmark, i'll have to wait for one more day as i replied to my own question :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a day after a fresh install, when i tried to browse the site i got a "The trial period for this product has expired" error.

Ran the configuraion Wizard once again and it all fixed it.

Comment: Enh, it's preferable an answer have a why, or at least an attempt at one, rather than "this random things worked for me, who knows, it may work for you."